# My.Application StartUp event

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am rewriting an application for printing shipping labels that we have been using for many years, because over those many years, many programmers have added bits and pieces to it, and it has become harder and harder to maintain.

While considering design choices, I came across catching the application's StartUp event in ApplicationEvents.vb, which I thought would be a good choice for this application because the main form is only displayed if there are more than 10 labels to print at a time (displays a progress bar if so, but mostly it does one label at a time and as such the progress bar isn't desired).

Now, whether this is a good choice I'm not sure, but while playing around with it I have found a need to exit the application from this event if certain criteria aren't met (invalid command line args, network directory not found in expected location, and a few other criteria). I have been unsuccessful in figuring out how to exit from the application if something like the above were to occur. The only thing close I have found is setting the `StartupEventArgs.Cancel` to `True`, but the documentation states that this only stops the main form from loading and if set to true should point code on a different processing path.

Is there a "proper" way to exit the application in the StartUp event? I've tried using `My.Application.Shutdown` which doesn't exist, and `RaiseEvent ShutDown()` which gives the error "Derived classes cannot raise base class events."

Linked here is the main doc I have been using for research (and the related links on the linked page):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4zch4d2(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use `End`?

Comment: You just need to set the Cancel property of the StartupEventArgs to True and it doesn't stop it from loading if it's that last piece in the method...

Comment: @436f6465786572 Read the question properly; the OP has already tried this without success.

Comment: It doesn't stop the main form from loading unless the cancel is at the beginning, he said it does. I explained that in my comment.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ I've never used `End` as it I have read before that it should be avoided when possible, as it stops execution of the program and doesn't release resources, etc. I've never had a need for it though, so now may be the time to do a little more research on it.

Comment: @RianBattle Using `End` is completely fine; if you need to release resources, save files, etc, then create a function that does it before `End` is executed.

Comment: After further testing with `StartupEventArgs.Cancel` it seems like setting it to true anywhere in the Startup event will (after continuing processing the rest of the Startup event code) cause the application to close. This seems to go against the MSDN documentation.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ it seems like that is the best way to go, i'll try to limit how many resources are actually opened in the Startup event so less can potentially go wrong when cleaning up before. Thanks.

Comment: @RianBattle Remember that .NET is a self-managing framework; it automatically manages memory. The only thing you really need to worry about are files.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ you are assuming it does all the time, right? I hope not. It tries it's best to manage memory... but doesn't help when object's are left hanging around.

Comment: @436f6465786572 The whole framework can be buggy and sometimes can remove stuff from the heap that you still want.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ yeah the framework can be at times . . .

Comment: @RianBattle as ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ  has explained you can use **End** here's a little tip you should consider:  End terminates your application without attending to any resources that might be open, you should try to close down cleanly before using it. For example, if your application has any forms open, you should close them before control reaches the **End** statement.

Comment: @436f6465786572 +1, but it's unlikely that any forms are open in the `StartUp` event, but it's something to note.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ correct, but it can be something else other than a form...

Comment: thank you both for all your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @436f6465786572 True, a couple of months ago I built a program that needed to note in its database when the program was shut down, did a similar thing in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `End` to immediately kill the process, note that:

- This will prematurely kill the process
- Any files being written to can become corrupted
- Any other activity related to the program will be terminated

To protect against file corruption, you could use a subroutine that 'finishes up' and then terminates the program, for example:

```
Private Sub finishUp()
    [..close files, forms, here..]
    End
End Sub
```

I did this myself for a gameserver program I made a couple of months ago; the program needed to note in the SQL database the startup and shutdown times. I made it log the shut-down time in a subroutine similar to the one above.

Note that the same subroutine could (and probably should) be used when you need the program to close at any other time.

Comment: Thanks! So far, all I have open is a database connection, but I'm just starting to flesh out everything that will need to be in the StartUp event. I'll do this, and make sure to add anything I open in the StartUp event just to be sure that it closes out properly before halting execution.